# Using ng-class with mutiple conditions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to set 1 of 3 different classes on a span based on the result of a function. My javascript below seems to be returning the correct value, however my markup is always showing the 'require-matched' class.
How can I write an ng-class directive to accommodate this?

HTML:

```
<span ng-class="{'require-empty': 0,
                                 'require-matched': 1,
                                 'require-not-matched':2 [form.username.$validators.status]}">
                </span>
```

JS:

```
ctrl.$validators.status = function (value) {
                var expression = /^[-\w]+$/;

                if (value != null && value != undefined && value != '' && value != ' ') {
                    if (expression.test(value))
                        return 1;
                    if (!expression.test(value))
                        return 2;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect usage of validation in Angular. `ctrl.$validators.status` should return boolean.

Comment: @dfsq What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Give me five mins to prepare a complete example of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect usage of validation in Angular. `ctrl.$validators.status` should return boolean: `true` for valid result (`required-matched` in your terminology) and `false` otherwise (`required-not-match`). In case of invalid validation `ngModelController` will receive boolean flag which you can use in view to style control or show error message.

`require-empty` that you have should be handled by `required` validator instead of making `status` validator do this also.

So what you would probably want to have:

```
ctrl.$validators.status = function(value) {
    if (value) {
        var expression = /^[-\w]+$/;
        return expression.test(value.trim());
    }
    return false;
}
```

or directive can be as concise as

```
ctrl.$validators.status = function(value) {
    return value && /^[-\w]+$/.test(value.trim());
}
```

Corresponding field in HTML will be (providing that the directive name is `status`):

```
<input type="text" name="test" ng-model="testModel" status required>

<div class="error" ng-show="testForm.test.$error.required">The field is required.</div>
<div class="error" ng-show="testForm.test.$error.status">The value should match pattern.</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/YALB4Vbi5FzNH5FCfwB5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, could you provide an example using ng-class instead of ng-show? Still having trouble determining when to provide which class to my markup

Comment: Do you really want these classes? I mean you automatically get validation classes that allows you to style form and field the way you want. Those are `ng-invalid-status` (require-not-matched) and `ng-invalid-required` (require-empty). The default state corresponds to `require-empty`.

Comment: I'm attempting to style a span element with classes that provide a different icon for each of the 3 states: value is empty, value matches expression, value does not match expression. So I do need my custom classes, as it is not just styling the form field in an error or valid state.

Comment: I see. So you can use `<span ng-class="{'require-empty': testForm.test.$error.required, 'require-matched': testForm.test.$error.status, 'require-not-match': !testForm.test.$error.status}">`

Comment: More generically, I'd like to do something like this: `<div ng-class="{'class1': expression_one, 'class2': expression_two, 'class3':expression_three}[status]"></div>`, where status is the operand. Is  this possible?

Comment: Why do you need `[status]`, this is enough: `ng-class="{'class1': expression_one, 'class2': expression_two, 'class3':expression_three}"`